# detect top and bottom toolbars of iphone are visible iphone safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

How can I detect if top and bottom toolbars are visible on iphone Safari browser? My mobile menu exists of 2 parts, top part is main menu which should have much height than bottom part, and bottom part is one menu link. When toolbars are visible only top part is shown on mobile safari browser which isn't user friendly and only if you scroll you can see menu bottom part.
That's why I need to check whether toolbars are visibe or not so can implement another code.

[**Here is my demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/246/) and one iphone toolbar screenshot where I highlighted toolbars.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var bottomH = jQuery(".bottom_part").outerHeight(true);
    var screenH = jQuery(window).height(); 
    var remainderh = screenH - bottomH;  
    jQuery(".top_part").height(remainderh - 20);

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var bottomH = jQuery(".bottom_part").outerHeight(true);
        var screenH = jQuery(window).height(); 
        var remainderh = screenH - bottomH;  
        jQuery(".top_part").height(remainderh - 20);
    });
});
```

[image]